# Document with multiple nested types

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a type of document that can have lots of nested type objects, how can I map all of these as nested without actually having to tediously specify a mapping for every single field in the document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen [Dynamic templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/dynamic-templates.html)?

> Dynamic templates allow you to define custom mappings that can be
>   applied to dynamically added fields based on:
>
> - the [datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/dynamic-mapping.html) detected by Elasticsearch, with [`match_mapping_type`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/dynamic-templates.html#match-mapping-type).
> - the name of the field, with [`match` and `unmatch`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/dynamic-templates.html#match-unmatch) or [`match_pattern`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/dynamic-templates.html#match-pattern).
> - the full dotted path to the field, with [`path_match` and `path_unmatch`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/dynamic-templates.html#path-match-unmatch).
>
> The original field name `{name}` and the detected datatype
>   `{dynamic_type}` [template variables](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/dynamic-templates.html#template-variables) can be used in the mapping
>   specification as placeholders.

So you could potentially use this example by adding some sort of special pattern to your field, so template would recognize it and map it as a nested object.

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "nested_objects": {
            "match":   "nested_*",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "nested"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

*P.S.* I haven't tested this myself. Let me know if this helps you.